# B+ Tree data structure for keys

Tags: c++, data-structures, b-tree

In a B+ Tree, I think there can be a maximum of M (the order of the B+Tree) - 1 keys for any given node.

Now when you want to insert a key with say value 7 into this tree with a order of 4:

```
10, 12
```

Then it would become this:

```
7, 10, 12
```

If the structure of a node is as such:

```
struct Node {
    int keys[MAX_SIZE];
    ...
};
```

Then that would mean you have to shift at most `MAX_SIZE` elements to the right if you were to insert at the beginning of the node. This is not the most ideal. I was wondering if there was a better where to store `keys`. If you stored each key as a linked list, that would provide better insertion but it would cost a lot more space.

What is the best way to store `keys`? In my scenario this `B+Tree` will be used **purely in memory**.

Comment: Using a B+Tree on a file is a lot more complex.

Comment: For this case the B+ tree will be purely in memory (as stated at the end of the question)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, pairing the key with a pointer to the subtree is a better idea than having a container of keys and a container of pointers.

```
struct Node;

struct Key_Subtree
{
    int key;
    Node * p_subtree;
};

struct Node
{
   std::vector<Key_Subtree> keys;
   Node * p_lesser_subtree;
};
```

The above structures allow better synchronization between keys and pointers to subtrees, than having parallel arrays (vectors).

Comment: You're right, but for my scenario I have to store a container of keys because in my case every single key contains the sum of the lengths of its corresponding child. This also allows access to children values without the extra level of indirection

Comment: You could add a field to the `Key_Subtree` to contain the "sum of the lengths of the child (subtree)".

Comment: The key is the sum of the lengths of the child though. I just do this so I reduce the level of indirection. But the problem still remains because you still have to shift all the keys over

Answer (score 0):

I like what SQL server does, having an array of record offsets at the end of each block and then a data area following the block header.

The actual data records need not be in-order it is only the order within the offset array that is important.

basically (though not an actual struct type due to variable layout):
struct block
{
blockk_header header; // includes offset to record offset array (
// includes either a record count or offset to record offset array
/* variable-sized record data */
/* variable-sized record offset array */
};

Note that the end of the offset array is *always* flush with the end of the block. I suppose if you know in code exactly what your key type is always going to be such games aren't needed but the above scheme allows for not caring what the key data is when handling blocks. Doing this also allows for using the same code for both B+ tree nodes and the data records (the former are simply stripped down data records plus a pointer to the next block).

Answer (score 0):

When your B+tree is only in memory, you make the nodes much smaller than you do for a B+tree that is backed by disk.

A good size is 2 cache lines, or 128 bytes on x86.  A that size, inserting at the beginning is not too expensive, and making the node bigger will not make your searches significantly faster.